# How to use rest-client with activeresource for a non-rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeresource, rest-client

I need to create an interface in rails which may not work directly with activeresource.

How would I create a model that uses rest-client to talk to the api directly?

Would it be better for me to keep using active resource but override the default behaviour, and how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I once made a Rails app which used a Java graph database (neo4j) which provides a REST api for CRUD operations (basically). I used the HTTParty gem and, for example, instead of the `create` method of a controller calling `ActiveRecord`, it called the REST api which returned JSON.

Comment: I didn't need Rails models for my graph database objects, but you can consider building them by parsing the REST response (performance will be affected)

Comment: i'm looking at rest_client in the controllers only now. I think the models look like too much overhead.